# Laravel with spatie/pdf-to-text 'could not find pdf book.pdf'

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I'm trying to use package [spatie/pdf-to-text](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text)    to convert pdf to text in my laravel project. Pdf located in public path: `pdf/book.pdf`  But I always get this error:

> Spatie \ PdfToText \ Exceptions \ PdfNotFound
>   could not find pdf book.pdf

```
$text = (new Pdf(public_path('pdf')))->setPdf('book.pdf')->text();

return $text;
```

What do I'm doing wrong?

Comment: tl;dr.. https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text the construct argument for the class is the path to the binary `pdftotext` not the path to the pdf file. And if the pdf is called `pdf/file.pdf` why are you setting `setPdf('book.pdf')`? I wonder why people take the time to make docs when there is stackoverflow..

Comment: Sorry m8, my mistake.   The file names are absolutely different from my real project. I just miss spell it here. But the idea is still same,  I want to change the path  `/usr/bin/pdftotext`  to  public_path('pdf').

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you please point me how can I change  `/usr/bin/pdftotext` to my custom path?

Comment: That's fine if you have the `pdftotext` binary in the public folder. But the issue is not with the binary but with the pdf file, hence the error message.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I still could not fix it, the program keeps looking in `/usr/bin/pdftotext` ... Or maybe i totally do not get it :(

Answer (score 1):

Input proper directory of your file to argument of setPdf. It should be

public_path('pdf/file/book.pdf')

You are placing it in wrong method. setPdf() method obviously has nothing to do with the constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

You may use wrong file path, need to place a file in "public//" and then use below function to get the string of file

```
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;

$pdf_string = Pdf::getText(public_path() . "/<foldername>/<pdffilename>);
```